# Unable to StartActivityForResult() with camera Intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent

this is pretty much a last resort. I have been trying to get a camera intent working to no avail. My end goal is to pass the filepath to another activity. I have tried pretty much every camera intent example out there and nothing appears to be working, and I receive a fatal exception when it goes to the startActivityForResult(). It saves the image, and nothing returns null. I have no idea what the issue is. Code follows

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.test;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;



import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static final int SELECT_IMAGE = 1;
    private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1337;
    private Uri imageUri;
    private ImageView mImageView;
    private Button mButton;
    private String path;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // create an intent to invoke a image capture device
                Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                File dir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);
                File output = new File(dir,"test.jpg");
                cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,Uri.fromFile(output));
                path = output.getAbsolutePath();
                Log.e("TEST", cameraIntent == null ? "true" : "false");
                Log.e("TEST", dir == null ? "true" : "false");
                Log.e("TEST", output == null ? "true" : "false");
                Log.e("TEST", path == null ? "true" : "false");
                System.out.println(CAMERA_REQUEST);

                // start the camera activity
                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
            }
        });
    }

    public void onSelectAnImage(View v) {
        Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
        Uri data = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).getPath());
        photoPickerIntent.setDataAndType(data, "image/*");
        startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, SELECT_IMAGE);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            switch (requestCode) {
            case SELECT_IMAGE:

                // get the URI of the image that the user selected.
                Uri picturePath = data.getData();           
                System.out.println(picturePath);        
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, ImageInformationActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("IMAGE_FILENAME", picturePath.toString());

                //intent.putExtra("uri", pass);
                // start the intent.
                startActivity(intent);

            case CAMERA_REQUEST:
                System.out.println(path);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**LogCat**

```
09-27 16:56:05.043: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(31741): <ConfigWindowMatch:2087>: Format RGBA_8888.
09-27 16:56:09.558: I/System.out(31741): content://media/external/images/media/1205
09-27 16:56:09.618: I/System.out(31741): /storage/sdcard0/DCIM/test.jpg
09-27 16:56:09.678: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(31741): <ConfigWindowMatch:2087>: Format RGBA_8888.
09-27 16:56:09.718: I/System.out(31741): android.widget.ImageView@41ef7f60
09-27 16:56:09.728: I/System.out(31741): android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor$AutoCloseInputStream@41ef9488
09-27 16:56:09.758: D/dalvikvm(31741): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 73K, 42% free 12365K/21315K, paused 22ms, total 22ms
09-27 16:56:09.868: D/dalvikvm(31741): GC_CONCURRENT freed 3K, 19% free 40105K/49095K, paused 2ms+2ms, total 21ms
09-27 16:56:10.349: I/System.out(31741): android.graphics.Bitmap@41eed2a0
09-27 16:56:10.349: I/Choreographer(31741): Skipped 39 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-27 16:56:10.379: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(31741): <ConfigWindowMatch:2087>: Format RGBA_8888.
09-27 16:56:12.521: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(31741): <ConfigWindowMatch:2087>: Format RGBA_8888.
09-27 16:56:12.571: E/SpannableStringBuilder(31741): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
09-27 16:56:12.571: E/SpannableStringBuilder(31741): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
09-27 16:56:13.522: E/TEST(31741): false
09-27 16:56:13.522: E/TEST(31741): false
09-27 16:56:13.522: E/TEST(31741): false
09-27 16:56:13.522: E/TEST(31741): false
09-27 16:56:13.522: I/System.out(31741): 1337
09-27 16:56:14.603: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(31741): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
09-27 16:56:20.840: W/dalvikvm(31741): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x411ef438)
09-27 16:56:20.850: E/AndroidRuntime(31741): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-27 16:56:20.850: E/AndroidRuntime(31741): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.example.test/com.example.test.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1337, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.example.test/com.example.test.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-27 16:56:20.850: E/AndroidRuntime(31741):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2639)
09-27 16:56:20.850: E/AndroidRuntime(31741):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2667)
09-27 16:56:20.850: E/AndroidRuntime(31741):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2140)
09-27 16:56:20.850: E/AndroidRuntime(31741):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3576)
09-27 16:56:20.850: E/AndroidRuntime(31741):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:143)
09-27 16:56:20.850: E/AndroidRuntime(31741):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1247)
09-27 16:56:20.850: E/AndroidRuntime(31741):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-27 16:56:20.850: E/AndroidRuntime(31741):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-27 16:56:20.850: E/AndroidRuntime(31741):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4950)
09-27 16:56:20.850: E/AndroidRuntime(31741):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-27 16:56:20.850: E/AndroidRuntime(31741):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-27 16:56:20.850: E/AndroidRuntime(31741):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)
09-27 16:56:20.850: E/AndroidRuntime(31741):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
09-27 16:56:20.850: E/AndroidRuntime(31741):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-27 16:56:20.850: E/AndroidRuntime(31741): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1337, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.example.test/com.example.test.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-27 16:56:20.850: E/AndroidRuntime(31741):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3205)
09-27 16:56:20.850: E/AndroidRuntime(31741):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2626)
09-27 16:56:20.850: E/AndroidRuntime(31741):    ... 13 more
09-27 16:56:20.850: E/AndroidRuntime(31741): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-27 16:56:20.850: E/AndroidRuntime(31741):    at com.android.internal.os.LoggingPrintStream.println(LoggingPrintStream.java:298)
09-27 16:56:20.850: E/AndroidRuntime(31741):    at com.example.test.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:86)
09-27 16:56:20.850: E/AndroidRuntime(31741):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5363)
09-27 16:56:20.850: E/AndroidRuntime(31741):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3201)
09-27 16:56:20.850: E/AndroidRuntime(31741):    ... 14 more
```

Comment: The NPE is on line 86 of the MainActivity class.  What's on that line?

Comment: I tried counting out the lines, can you confirm it's this line?  `super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);`

Comment: If you're using a camera to find an image, you won't find much success there.  A camera activity will only take a picture, an Image Picker activity (like the Gallery app) will find the picture and provide a path to its location on the disk.

Comment: line 86 is

    case CAMERA_REQUEST:
    System.out.println(path);
   }

Comment: Then yeah, that's the source of your problem.  A camera activity will typically return an image, not a path.  It's up to you to save the image which creates the path.  If you want the path of a pre-existing image, use a picker activity, not a camera one.

Comment: What i am trying to do is, on button, open camera, take photo, then i need to pass the path to my new activity, and then populate an imageview

EDIT: the path var is returning the path of the image, is this not how i should be doing it?

Comment: Please read above.  The Camera Activity is returning an image.  The image has not been saved yet.  Consequently, the image returned has NO path.  You have to save the image before it has a path.

Comment: Im sorry if I am being very elementary, as i am in an intro course, but i am not really following you. so lets say my camera intent is this: http://pastebin.com/eP5GsM6X. it runs and saves image file. So, perhaps my real question should be how to set the imageview in my new activity to this file?

Comment: frankly, I don't understand Prmths' comments, they seem wrong. If you get a success, then the images IS saved. The path attribute is null (this is why you get NullPointerException) because the activity got recreated, but you don't need the path attribute - the code that calculates the path is right there, in the onClick method.

Comment: @user2824993, I was incorrect earlier in saying the image has no path.  It does as it's saved to a default location with a default name if a path isn't defined in the requesting `Intent`.  @fdreger is correct when he says you already know the path, you are putting it in the original Intent in the onCreate method.  @fdreger, I'm not sure I understand why the `Activity` is recreated, it should be on the backstack since it was only stopped, not destroyed.

Comment: @Prmths: being on a backstack guarantees only that the bundle with saved state and original starting Intent are preserved. Activity object itself may be destroyed and recreated when user presses the "back" button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android throws NPE (which is a scandal in itself) every time you try to log a null.

The problem is that you believe that the resulting intent contains `Uri` of the photo taken. **It does not**.

Camera app does not have to tell you where the image is stored, **because you already know**. It was your decision and you have chosen the Uri yourself, sending the EXTRA_OUTPUT.

**update**: Feel free to ignore my answer if I misunderstood the problem. You can prevent such misunderstandings by providing line numbers (at least tell us which lines are mentioned in the stacktrace) and only publishing parts of the code that actually don't work. As some other answer already tells, it might as well be due to `path` being null.

Comment: noted for the future. first post here, my apologies. thanks for taking the time to read this

Answer (score 1):

Your `path` can be null beacuse Activty can be destroyed and recreated after starting camera application.
As fdreger said, you can use [android.provider.MediaStore.html.EXTRA_OUTPUT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#EXTRA_OUTPUT) extra. 
Here is a snippet: https://gist.github.com/koral--/6173683

Answer (score 0):

It says specifically in logcat that the data you returned is null. In your cameraIntent activity you need to specifically set the results you want to return to your original activity:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent();
 intent.putExtra("result",yourresult);
 setResult(RESULT_OK,intent);     
 finish();
```